# Google Translator does not appear automatically anymore

Tags: google-translate

When I was using WhatsApp and chatting with my foreign friends, when I copied their text, the Google Translator was automatically appearing.

But now, after the Android update, it doesn't happen. I tried settings in the translator app but there is nothing to enable that.

Settings > Tap to translate > Enable

did not work.

How can I make the translator app button automatically appear whenever I copy a foreign language text?

Comment: Have you tried clear data and followed the procedure again?

Comment: Just in case it's related, could you also mention the phone model and the Android version?